# Modify report range sql query only return current year

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, date-arithmetic

Currently my data picking up the current year and previous year. How can I change only to display current year only. Please advise.

Here is my code below:

```
@minimumDate date = DATEADD(yy,-1,( DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,@parReportDate), 0)) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to compute the first day of this year?

```
declare @minimumDate date = datefromparts(year(getdate()), 1, 1);
```

That would the (inclusive) lower bound of a date range filter. You might also need to first day of next year, as an excluding upper bound:

```
declare @maximumDate date = datefromparts(year(getdate()) + 1, 1, 1);
```